# The notation $g{.}h$ in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In the paper [On the O'Nan Scott Theorem for primitive permutation groups](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_44_03%2FS144678870003216Xa.pdf&code=390c373663b91e6414e1b68b258da7cd) the notation $A{.}B$ appears, meaning that $A$ is a [group extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension) of $B$. On the same page, a similar notation appears:

> $W = \{ (a_1, \ldots, a_k).\pi \mid a_i \in \operatorname{Aut}(T), \pi \in S_k, a_i \equiv a_j \mod{\operatorname{Inn}(T)} \mbox{ for all } i,j \}$

But what does the notation $g{.}h$ applied to elements of some group mean?

Comment: $A.B$ does not mean that $A$ is a group extension of $B$. It is $A.B$ that is the extension, and it is used to denote any group $W$ with a normal subgroup ismorphic to $A$ with quotient group isomorphic to $B$. (This is ATLAS notation.) In the definition of $W$, the . is just being used to separate the two componenets of an element of a semidirect product. So the two uses of the . symbol are distinct.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, thanks. But in the paper they explicitly write that $W$ "not necessarily splits" [right in the paragraph under this definition], so they do not seem to suppose it has the form of a semidirect product... so I am not sure if the dot notation for elements could mean that...?

Comment: I know, but it is still true that $W$ is defined as a split extension. The non-splitting is regarding $W$ as a different extension.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, somehow $Out(T)$ does not appear in the first "split" definition, but in the (possibly) non-split extension written in the paragraph. I somehow do not get why they want to consider this non-split overgroup when we have a definition as a semidirect product at hand. But guess I miss something, and I have a poor understanding of the O'Nan-Scott Thm overall...